# Trying to reorder multiple MovieClips based of distance of player

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, 3d

I started off by making the stage width: 800, height 600.

Then I added a blank MovieClip to the stage and rotated it for a 3d-ish look. I then added a map graphic and player graphic to the black MovieClip. Then I placed objects to the map graphic. Basically when the up key is pressed it moves the map graphic and when the left/right keys are pressed it rotates the blank MovieClip.

Now the problem is when I try to get the distance between the objects on the map graphic and the player graphic, and trying to reorder them based off the distance. For some reason when I use (trace(Ground.getChildAt(0)); I get [object Shape] instead of [object Crate].

I'm not sure if that is the whole problem or that maybe I'm not sorting them right. Any help with this would be most appreciated.

Here is the the code:

```
import flash.events.Event;  
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;  
import flash.display.MovieClip;  

//Changing Perspective  
root.transform.perspectiveProjection.projectionCenter=new Point (400,0);

//Blank MoveClip  
var World:MovieClip = new MovieClip();  
World.x = 400;  
World.y = 50;  
World.z = -700;  
World.rotationX = -90;  
addChild(World);  

//Map Graphic  
var Ground:evergreen = new evergreen();  
Ground.x = 0;  
Ground.y = 0;  
World.addChild(Ground);  

//Player Graphic  
var Player:Test_Objects = new Test_Objects();  
Player.x = 0;  
Player.y = 0;  
Player.rotationX = 90;  
Player.scaleX = 0.1;  
Player.scaleY = 0.1;  
World.addChild(Player);  

//Crate Graphics  
var Box_X:Array = new Array();  
var Box_Y:Array = new Array();  
var Box_Rotate_X:Array = new Array();  
var Box_Rotate_Z:Array = new Array();  
Box_X = [0,     0,  -50,    50];  
Box_Y = [0, -100,   -50,    -50];  
Box_Rotate_X = [90, 90, 90, 90];  
Box_Rotate_Z = [0,  0,  90, 90];  
for (var Sides:int = 0; Sides < Box_X.length; Sides++)  
{  
    var Box:Crate = new Crate();  
    Box.x = Box_X[Sides];  
    Box.y = Box_Y[Sides];  
    Box.rotationX = Box_Rotate_X[Sides];  
    Box.rotationZ = Box_Rotate_Z[Sides];  
    Box.Distances = 0;  
    Ground.addChild(Box);  
}  

//Tree Graphics  
var Object_List_X:Array = new Array();  
var Object_List_Y:Array = new Array();  
Object_List_X = [-200, -150, -125];  
Object_List_Y = [-200, -150, -125];  
for (var CreateObject:int = 0; CreateObject < Object_List_X.length; CreateObject++)  
{  
    var New_Object:Test_Objects = new Test_Objects();  
    New_Object.x = Object_List_X[CreateObject];  
    New_Object.y = Object_List_Y[CreateObject];  
    New_Object.rotationX = 90;  
    Ground.addChild(New_Object);  
}  

//Keyboard Listeners  
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, Key_Pressed);  
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, Key_Released);  

//Keys Variables  
var Move_Forward:Boolean = false;  
var Ground_Rotate:int = 0;  

function Key_Pressed (event:KeyboardEvent)  
{  
    //trace(event.keyCode)  
    if (event.keyCode == 37)  
    {  
        Ground_Rotate = 1;  
    }  
    if (event.keyCode == 39)  
    {  
        Ground_Rotate = -1;  
    }  
    if (event.keyCode == 38)  
    {  
        Move_Forward = true;  
    }  
    //trace(World.rotationY);  
}  

function Key_Released (event:KeyboardEvent)  
{  
    if ((event.keyCode == 37) || (event.keyCode == 39))  
    {  
        Ground_Rotate = 0;  
    }  
    if (event.keyCode == 38)  
    {  
        Move_Forward = false;  
    }  
}  

//Moving Listener  
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Move_Ground);  

//Distance Variables  
var Object_Array_D:Array = new Array();  
var DX:Number;  
var DY:Number;  
var Distance:int;  

function Move_Ground (event:Event)  
{  
    //Get Distances  
    for (var SortID:int = 0; SortID < Ground.numChildren; SortID++)  
    {  
        DX = (Ground.getChildAt(SortID).x + Ground.x) - Player.x;  
        DY = (Ground.getChildAt(SortID).y + Ground.y) - Player.y;  
        Distance = Math.sqrt(DX * DX + DY * DY);  
        Object_Array_D[SortID] = Distance;  
    }  
    //Sort Objects  
    SortOBJECTS();  

    //Update Rotation  
    Player.rotationZ -= Ground_Rotate;  
    World.rotationY += Ground_Rotate;  
    if (World.rotationY < 1)  
    {  
        World.rotationY += 360;  
    }  
    if (World.rotationY > 360)  
    {  
        World.rotationY += -360;  
    }  

    //Update Movement  
    if (Move_Forward)  
    {  
        if ((World.rotationY > 0) && (World.rotationY < 91))  
        {  
            //var Ground_Rotation:int = int(World.rotationY);  
            //trace(Ground_Rotation);  
            Ground.y += (((90 - World.rotationY) * 3) / 90);  
            Ground.x += ((World.rotationY * 3) / 90);  
        }  
        if ((World.rotationY > 90) && (World.rotationY < 181))  
        {  
            Ground.y -= (((World.rotationY - 90) * 3) / 90);  
            Ground.x += (((90 - (World.rotationY - 90)) * 3) / 90);  
        }  
        if ((World.rotationY > 180) && (World.rotationY < 271))  
        {  
            Ground.x -= (((World.rotationY - 180) * 3) / 90);  
            Ground.y -= (((90 - (World.rotationY - 180)) * 3) / 90);  
        }  
        if ((World.rotationY > 270) && (World.rotationY < 361))  
        {  
            Ground.y += (((World.rotationY - 270) * 3) / 90);  
            Ground.x -= (((90 - (World.rotationY - 270)) * 3) / 90);  
        }  
    }  
}  

function SortOBJECTS ()  
{  
    for (var Sort1:int = 1; Sort1 < Object_Array_D.length; Sort1++)  
    {  
        for (var Sort2:int = 1; Sort2 < Object_Array_D.length; Sort2++)  
        {  
            if (Object_Array_D[Sort1] < Object_Array_D[Sort2])  
            {  
                Ground.setChildIndex(Ground.getChildAt(Sort1), Sort2);  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have implemented bubble sort incorrectly. `Sort2` should run from `Sort1+1` to end, not from 1. Also if your `evergreen` class has a nested MC or a nested Shape, it can end up being sorted too.

Comment: It doesn't work at first, but after awhile of roaming around the screen it started working. I'm running it the flash professional to test it. Does it need load time in order to work right from the beginning?

Comment: It should not, perhaps you didn't do something else that was remedied by repeated readjusting and sorting of the results. It's hard to tell based on given code.

Comment: Ah I see. I inserted a copy of the for statement used before the SortOBJECTS function and it works perfectly.